# Is there any way to recover a file that has been accidentally overwritten (in the terminal)?

Tags: command-line, data-recovery

As usual, I needed to generate some files by means of a program like this:
`.../charmm < 0.inp > 0.out &`

However, I made the mistake of doing the following:
`.../charmm < 0.inp > 0.inp &`

Thus, my input file was overwritten with the output file. Very careless of me.

Does anyone know of a way to be able to recover it, please?

PS.: If it helps, this happened on a remote cluster that I access via SSH, it wasn't on my computer.

Comment: if the output was empty and it is done on a HDD: --maybe--. Very important: stop using the disk. Take it out and put it into another machine mounting it read only. Or make a disk dump pf this disk and put it on an external disk (or somewhere else you can put it) make it read only if possible. Then install testdisk in that system and have it scan for the file.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind, however, this occurred on a remote cluster that I access via SSH. I will try to contact the cluster manager to see if the data can be copied to an external disk and then scan it as you suggest.

Comment: if you can do make an answer and accept it ;) clusters are always fun :P